# Github enterprise : get repository name from its path on the server

Tags: github

On my github enterprise server, I have a repository stored in say :

/data/repositories/9/nw/90/87/27/100013262/20166.git

How can I identify which repository is related to this storage path ?

Answer (score 0):

I finally got an answer from Github support.

In the example above, 20166 is the REPOSITORY_ID of the repository.

It is therefore possible to obtain the name of the repository in two ways :

1. connect directly to the github enterprise server (you need admin access to the server) and use the ghe-nwo command

   ghe-nwo  $REPOSITORY_ID
2. use the web browser and search in the admin section  (you need to be site admin)

   http:///stafftools/search?query=$REPOSITORY_ID